# Highlighting an Hourly Candle

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to highlight the 16:00 bar on the 1H timeframe everyday but can't seem to get the code right. The only piece I'm missing is the code to pinpoint the bar and time_close doesn't seem to be working for this. Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Update: This code seems to be working for the most part but randomly skips some bars, ie. doesn't highlight them. I'm not sure why. The code is as follows:

```
study("1600 bars", overlay=true)
t = time(timeframe.period, "1600-1700")

fourUp = t and close > open
fourDown = t and close < open

barcolor(fourUp ? color.white : na, title="Four Up")
barcolor(fourDown ? color.yellow : na, title="Four Down")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time()` by default will exclude weekends. But you can specify which days of the week you want to work with. Just add `:1234567` to your session string if you want your script to work seven days.

```
//@version=4
study("1600 bars", overlay=true)
t = time(timeframe.period, "1600-1700:1234567")

fourUp = t and close > open
fourDown = t and close < open

barcolor(fourUp ? color.white : na, title="Four Up")
barcolor(fourDown ? color.yellow : na, title="Four Down")
```

Comment: what a cool feature! Thanks for point that out!